# Configuring the Tomcat Plugin of Munin

Tags: tomcat6, munin

It would be great if anyone can share a working configuration for the tomcat_ plugin of munin. I need to monitor several tomcat instances on one machine.

So far I can't figure out:

- which are the available metrics for the tomcat_ plugin? (documentation is quite poor - at least what I've managed to find)
- how to configure it correctly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

share my experiences,hope it helps

**step1**: enable tomcat plugins

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/munin/plugins/tomcat_access /etc/munin/plugins/tomcat_access
sudo ln -s /usr/share/munin/plugins/tomcat_jvm /etc/munin/plugins/tomcat_jvm
sudo ln -s /usr/share/munin/plugins/tomcat_threads /etc/munin/plugins/tomcat_threads
sudo ln -s /usr/share/munin/plugins/tomcat_volume /etc/munin/plugins/tomcat_volume
```

**step2**: config tomcat manager status page where the plugin read info from

edit tomcat-users.xml and add

```
<user username="munin" password="munin" roles="manager"/>
<role rolename="manager"/>
```

access http://munin:munin@localhost:8080/manager/status?XML=true to see if it works.
check official document for details:[Manager App HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access)

**step3**: config tomcat plugins

edit /etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/munin-node and add

```
[tomcat_*]
env.ports 8080
env.user munin
env.password munin
```

**step4**: local check

run and check messages.

> /etc/munin/plugins/tomcat_jvm

normally you need install simple xml support,

```
sudo apt-get install libxml-simple-perl
#OR
sudo yum install perl-XML-Simple
```

**step5**: update munin node

sudo /etc/init.d/munin-node restart

check you graphics, it should works.

Comment: Thank you for the instructions, I still hadn't the chance to check it out and verify your answer, but I'll mark the question as answered. If problems appear, I'll add to the discussion.

Comment: You shouldn't run munin plug-ins that way. Instead, use the provided command, as in `munin-run tomcat_jvm`, so you will also check that munin configuration for finding and running your plug-in is correct.

Answer (score 7):

First, it's a great answer! However, when you mention manually running and checking using "/etc/munin/plugins/tomcat_jvm," this doesn't pick up the environment variables from /etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/munin-node (i.e. user/password), so it fails. The correct way is to use munin-run:

```
$ sudo /etc/munin/plugins/tomcat_jvm
free.value U
used.value U
max.value U

$ sudo munin-run tomcat_jvm
free.value 13894584
used.value 40762440
max.value 1073741824
```

Also, I'm running Tomcat 7 and some of the tomcat plugins expect connectors with the name of the form `http-${PORT}` but my connectors are of the form `http-apr-${PORT}` so I also needed to add this to the `[tomcat_*]` stanza of `munin-node`:

```
env.connector "http-apr-8081"
```

Answer (score 3):

My reputation doesn't allow commenting, but correct `env.connector` is crucial for other plugins than `tomcat_jvm`. In my case I needed to drop quotation marks ("), i.e.

```
 env.connector jk-127.0.0.1-8009
```

If you can't find the correct connector name, try either

```
$ lynx http://localhost:8080/manager/html
```

or

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/manager/status?XML=true -u munin:munin | grep connector
```

Also note, that in tomcat 6.0.30 or later, the roles for manager are more fine-grained. I haven't yet tried myself, but according to the documentation role `manager-status` in `tomcat-users.xml` should work in this case.